# Mocking Blobclient.DownloadContentAsync() using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

am I mocking the method below correctly coz, when called its not returning the result:

```
var blobContent = new BinaryData("this is test data");
var downloadResult = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(content: blobContent);
var response =  Response.FromValue(downloadResult, blobContainerClientResponseMock.Object);

mockBlobClientTrue.Setup(client => client.DownloadContentAsync(default))
          .ReturnsAsync(response);
```

I tried different ways, but no result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm avoiding using Moq at the moment because of the security concerns but I have the following solution using NSubstitute. i think you can reverse engineer it from this:

First use the BlobsModelFactory to build your result:

```
var t = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(content: BinaryData.FromString("data here"));
```

Then you wrap this in a Azure.Response:

```
var val = Response.FromValue(t, Substitute.For<Response>());
```

And finally the async return:

```
var returnVal =  Task.FromResult(val);
```

You would then want to setup your mocked to return that "returnVal" variable. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to translate Webezine's answer to an actual Moq solution, since it worked well for me. (Thanks, Webezine!)
Building on Qader's original code:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs; // BlobsModelFactory
using Azure; // Response


var blobContent = new BinaryData.FromString("this is test data");
var downloadResult = BlobsModelFactory.BlobDownloadResult(content: blobContent);

// Empty Response mock to merge with since I only care about the downloadResult. Modify at will.
var response =  Response.FromValue(downloadResult, new Mock<Response>().Object); 

mockBlobClientTrue.Setup(client => client.DownloadContentAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(response));
```